# Extracting some rows and columns

Tags: matlab, eigen

I was wondering if there is a way to subset a matrix in EIGEN into another Matrix based on some condition.

For example in MATLAB, one can do this: Let `A` be a matrix of size *5*-by-*5*.

```
B=A(1:3,2:3)
```

This will create a new matrix `B` from `A` with dimensions *3*-by-*2* and with elements from `A` at the relevant indices.

Comment: Have you opened the [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html)? Or are you looking for a different API than `.block()`?

Comment: Another great resource when comparing with MATLABs basic operations can be found [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt).

Comment: @ggael, you are right. I shortly realised I was looking for the block function after I posted this. But if I understood correctly, there is no way I can index a matrix using a conditional statement and subset a matrix... for instance: `B=A(A(1,:)<3,:)`. I understood that I could use .array() and use to find out the elements which satisfy my condition... but I cannot directly use it to index it in C++. Please let me know if I mis understood this, I am quiet new to C++ and Eigen...

Comment: yes that's right, that feature will come later...