# Erase rows from Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, erase

I have a `Eigen::MatrixXd` and a `vector<int>` of the indexes of that rows that I need to erase from the original matrix.

Is there a way to achieve this result as fast as possible?

Example:

```
Matrix:
 1
 2
 4
 0
```

Indexes of rows to remove {0, 2}.

```
Matrix:
 2
 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is you'll have to roll your own, i.e. create a `VectorXd` of the size of the `std::vector` and fill it manually in a loop. When asked if a Matlab style conditional creation of matrices (`B=A(A(1,:)<3,:)`) exists, the dev (ggael) indicated that that [feature would come later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652497/extracting-some-rows-and-columns#comment55112558_33652497). I wouldn't be surprised if it's a SO style 6-8 weeks ;)